# Finding the [indexpath.row] value in a TableView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, tableview, indexpath

Essentially I am attempting to change a variable when a specific row is selected however, the code is still printing -1. Here is all my code relating. I am trying to be able to click a certain tableview cell and then be able to print out that text. Would the searchBar effect my values? I first code the tableview and then the searchbar and then I implement a submit button which prints the values of my variables.

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UISearchBarDelegate, UITableViewDelegate {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    
    let Data = ["dog","cat","goat"]
    
    var filteredData: [String]!
    
    var num = -1
    
    var animal: String = ""
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if tableView != nil {
            self.tableView.dataSource = self
        }
        filteredData = Data
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
        cell.textLabel?.text = filteredData[indexPath.row]
        print(indexPath.row)
        return cell
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return filteredData.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            num = 0
        }
        if indexPath.row == 1 {
            num =  1
        }
        if indexPath.row == 2 {
            num = 2
        }
    }
    
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        filteredData = searchText.isEmpty ? Data : Data.filter { (item: String) -> Bool in
            // If dataItem matches the searchText, return true to include it
            return item.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive, range: nil, locale: nil) != nil
        }
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
    
    func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        self.searchBar.showsCancelButton = true
    }
    
    func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searchBar.showsCancelButton = false
        searchBar.text = ""
        searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    }
    
    @IBAction func Submit(_ sender: Any) {
        print(num)
        print(filteredData.count)
        if num == 0 {
            animal = "dog"
        }
        if num == 1 {
            animal = "cat"
        }
        if num == 2 {
            animal = "goat"
        }
        print(animal)
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to put the full table code. right now, what you have shown is insufficient.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues that are not allowing you to achieve what you want:

The `==` operator is checking if two variables are equal to each other, not assigning one variable to another, and it will return a boolean value, either `true` or `false`. In the body of your `if` statements, change `==` to `=` to assign a value to the variable num.

Change your code to:

```swift
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        num = 0
    }
    if indexPath.row == 1 {
        num =  1
    }
    if indexPath.row == 2 {
        num = 2
    }
}
```

After seeing your updated code, it looks like you only set the `dataSource` of the tableView and not the delegate. You need to add the line to `viewDidLoad`:

```swift
tableView.delegate = self
```

Also, instead of having multiple `if` statements to check the `indexPath`, you could replace that entire body of code with one line:

```swift
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    num = indexPath.row
}
```

Comment: I attempted your answer but the value I received is still -1

Comment: How and where are you printing the value of num? Are you changing the value of num somewhere else too?

Comment: Hey @Mark, see my update answer - I believe that I found the root of the problem.

Comment: I have not changed the num, after I press a button it will print the number

Comment: Unfortunately I have tried what you have given to me but it still doesn't work, thank you so much

Comment: @Mark is it possible that "filteredData" is empty? After the line `filteredData = Data`, write `print(filteredData.count)` and run your application. Hopefully, this will give us some more direction.

Comment: when I print the filtered Data the value that is outputted is 3

Comment: Thank you. When and where are you calling `print(num)` to see -1 in the output?

Comment: At the Action for the Submit Button.

Comment: And when is Submit called? Before or after selecting an item in the table view?

Comment: After the the item in the table view is selected